# find browser page title with multiple instances open, multiple tabs

Tags: vb.net, powershell, vbscript

I have more than one instance of Firefox open, multiple tabs in each, and Chrome also running.  I wish to be able to find which tab of which browser is running Pandora, for example.

I am working primarily in VBScript, but can tackle PowerShell and might have access to VB.net.

Comment: Add some code or explain clearly what you have done so far

Comment: Internet Explorer is the shell's browser and the only programmable browser. `:` is the same as CRLF in VBScript. `Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application"):
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows:
For Each window in AllWindows:msgbox window.locationname:If window.locationname="Scripts" then window.quit:
Next`

Answer (score 3):

With VBScript you need a third party component to get access to that kind of information. Otherwise your only option is to [shell out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a.aspx) and parse the output of the [`tasklist`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx) command.

```vb
searchTerm = "Pandora"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ps = sh.Exec("tasklist /v /fo csv")
data = ps.StdOut.ReadAll

searchTerm = "Pandora"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "^""(?:chrome|firefox|iexplore|opera)\.exe"""
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each line In Split(data, vbNewLine)
  If re.Test(line) Then
    fields = Split(Mid(line, 2, Len(line)-2), """,""")
    If InStr(fields(UBound(fields)), searchTerm) > 0 Then
      pid = CInt(fields(1))
    End If
  End If
Next

sh.AppActivate pid
```

In PowerShell it's a lot easier to do this kind of thing, since [`Get-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) already provides you with the window titles.

```bsh
$searchTerm = 'Pandora'
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like "*$searchTerm*" }
```

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing in VBScript using the same libraries as powershell. `Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2"):Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where name='Calculator.exe'"):For Each objItem in colItems:msgbox objItem.name & " " & objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine:Next`

Comment: @Noodles No. The [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) class doesn't provide a property with the window title.